# How do you change the PATH used in an external makefile build using XCode?

Tags: xcode, path, makefile

I currently have a project that I'm building with a makefile. This project includes some additional software (jflex) which is not on one of the default system search paths (it's installed to (/opt/local/bin/). My .profile file adds this directory to my PATH, and so building the project from a terminal window succeeds.

However, if I try to run the makefile from within XCode (XCode project with an externally managed makefile), it fails since it's not looking in /opt/local/bin for jflex, and as such can't find it.

How can I change the settings of my XCode project to correctly build from within XCode? I assume there's some kind of path setting in XCode, or some kind of additional argument I can have XCode give to make so that it doesn't fail. Alternately, I could hardcode the path into my makefile if I could detect that it was being run from XCode (although this is the less preferable option for me, since my makefile will sometimes need to be called from the command line and I'd rather keep it simple).

I'm relatively new to using XCode, so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the best way, But can you launch XCode from command line. It will inherit the Path from it.

Or, in the XCode launcher change:

```
XCode
```

to

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin/ XCode
```

may work (depending on launcher)

Or, did you relaunch the launcher/window manager (logout and back in again after setting .profile)?

Comment: There weren't any .profile changes between launching the window manager and trying this - so it's safe to assume it wasn't just waiting for an update. However, I'm not on a machine where I can test the alternate launcher suggestion at the moment, so I'll leave this without accepting until I have a chance to actually try it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `make` directly, you could call a shell script as the "Build Tool" in the "External Build Tool Configuration" pane. Then modify the path in the shell script and call `make` from there, i.e.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
make
```

Don't forget to set permissions such that Xcode can run the script, and provide the full path to the script as the "Build Tool".

Comment: I had to write `/absolute/path/to/make "$@"` instead of just `make`, but that worked, thanks.